# Purpose of RETURNTRANSFER constant in curl_setopt() in PHP

Tags: php

I want to know about the details of working of curl in PHP.

What is the use of `curl_setopt(ch,curl_returntransfer,true)`

I have searched many websites but didn't get the answer. So please tell me about this particular function. Why we are using `CURL_RETURNTRANSFER` constant?

Comment: You don't have to search many sites, this one site http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

According to [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

> set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER TRUE to return the transfer as a string of
>   the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.

Comment: Then what Is the purpose of Boolean value??

Comment: 'CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER' is the name of option.. If the value of this option is set to 'true', then return value instead of outputting directly.